# How tensorflow Train, Validation, Test Works on face recognition?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I'm working on face recognition.
I used to train the data using TensorFlow retrain.py

my questions are... 
 1. How Tensorflow works?
 2. is it using CNN?
 3. correct me if I am wrong 
 4. step for training the model - provide the images -> resizing the images ->bottleneck -> using CNN for the processing? ->show graph as the output?
 5. I need some references for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 — Tensorflow is a math library that is used for machine learning. Think about it as the OpenCV for Computer Vision or Bootstrap for Web Development.

2 — Yes, Tensorflow does use Convoloutional Neural Networks. It has a specialized library called Keras for this.

3 — Generally yes, but there is a lot more that goes into it. Here is more detailed process:

a — You provide the images, or as known as data sets. If you want to create a model that identifies dogs from cats, you should have 4 data sets;

**Training folders**

--------------- dog folder

------------------------------ dog1.jpg

------------------------------ dog2.jpg

--------------- cat folder

------------------------------ cat1.jpg

------------------------------ cat2.jpg

**Validation folders**

--------------- dog folder

------------------------------ dog3.jpg

------------------------------ dog4.jpg

--------------- cat folder

------------------------------ cat3.jpg

------------------------------ cat4.jpg

b — Yes resizing is crucial for vision machine learning but you should also do other modifications to your data sets pictures. For example, rotating, skewing, and flipping. Why? because you want to train your model to identify the object on various positions. For example, if your data sets contain dogs standing up, it will not identify dogs sleeping or laying on their backs, so you need to flip the images where dogs are standing up. Luckily, you don't have to do this manually because Keras offers you a class that does all the image loading, resizing.....etc for you called ImageDataGenerator. Read more about it [here](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/)

[image]

c- The bottleneck is an architecture of Neural Networks that generally helps avoid over fitting. Not every model follows the bottleneck architecture. This is the most challenging part of Machine Learning, finding the right architecture and layer combination and parameters to achieve high accuracy. There are already built models for different applications in the internet so you don't have to start designing your Neural Network architcture from scratch. For example, there is a model called Yolo which identifies various objects (persons, shoes, cellphone, fridges...etc). Luckily, Keras allows you to load in external models and add your modifications to it to fit your application, and this is what most data scientists do these days lol.

d- You are already using CNN processing in stage c.

e — Correct, the graphs and output should outline how accurate your model is. Accuracy is measured by testing the model performance on the validation data that you provided in stage a.

Unfortunately, I don't have references for this, but I learned these informations from taking the following courses:

[Introduction to TensorFlow for Artificial Intelligence, Machine Learning, and Deep Learning](https://www.coursera.org/learn/introduction-tensorflow/home/welcome)

[Convolutional Neural Networks in TensorFlow](https://www.coursera.org/learn/convolutional-neural-networks-tensorflow/home/welcome)

Comment: nah for the Keras itself Sir. because I use the Tensorflow [retrain.py] (https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/blob/master/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py)

am i using keras here ?

Comment: but anyw Thank you for yr help sir.

Comment: The repo you posted doesn't use Keras library functions, instead, it uses manually implemented functions.  Using Keras is optional in machine learning, but you will have to implement your own functions from scratch. For example, notice in line 598 the contributor implemented their own function `def should_distort_images` for point b in my answer. In Keras, that function is already written for you within the ImageDataGenerator class.